# OpenGL ES - Reducing texture quality and texture size

Tags: ios, image, opengl-es, glreadpixels

Is it possible to "degrade" the quality of textures in OpenGL ES?  By degrade I mean make the images more pixelated/blocky/blurry etc.

My goal is to reduce the size of textures to help `glReadPixels` run faster (transfer less bytes from VRAM to RAM).

Perhaps I can do something before calling `glCopyTexImage2D` such that the copied texture is lower quality (and hopefully a smaller size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render your scene to an FBO (frame buffer object) that is a smaller size than the display.

Note that reducing the size of the textures used to render your scene won't reduce the size of the data glReadPixels has to read back.

Comment: Ok cool. How can I reduce the amount of data `glReadPixels` reads back?  Can I somehow read back a smaller image then expand it later so it becomes more pixelated, blurry etc?